# Rename list of .mp4 with C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <errno.h>


int main ()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");
    DIR *d;
    int test = 0,j,h;
    struct dirent *dir;
    d = opendir(".");
    srand(time(NULL));
    if (d)
    {
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
        {
            for (j=0;j<strlen(dir->d_name);j++);
            char nome[j+1];
            strcpy(nome,dir->d_name);
            nome[j] = '\0';
            FILE *file;
            file = fopen(nome,"r");
            printf("%s\n", nome);
            for (int i=0;i<nome[i]!='\0';i++){
                if (nome[i] == '.' && nome[i+1] == 'm' && nome[i+2] == 'p' && nome[i+3] == '4'){
                    test = 1;
                    break;
                }

            }
            if (test == 1) {

                char newname[15];
                newname[0] = '.';
                newname[1] = '\\';
                newname[2] = 'n';
                newname[3] = 'e';
                newname[4] = 'w';
                newname[5] = '\\';
                h=rand()%127;
                h = 'A' + rand() % 26;;
                newname[6] = h;
                h=rand()%127;
                h = 48 + rand() % 10;;
                newname[7] = h;
                h=rand()%127;
                h = 'A' + rand() % 26;;
                newname[8] = h;
                h=rand()%127;
                h = 48 + rand() % 10;;
                newname[9] = h;
                h=rand()%127;
                h=0;
                newname[10] = '.';
                newname[11] = 'm';
                newname[12] = 'p';
                newname[13] = '4';
                newname[14] = '\0';

                int ret = rename(nome, newname);
                if (ret) perror("rename failed because"); //rename failed because: Permission denied
                fprintf(stderr, "renaming '%s' to '%s' failed\n", nome, newname); //renaming 'video.mp4' to '.\new\T6N5.mp4' failed
                printf("Value of errno: %d\n ", errno); //Value of errno: 13
                system("pause");
            }


        }
        closedir(d);
    }

   return(0);
}

//curiosity: the following code works fine

int main ()
{
   int ret;
    int h;
    char newname[15];
                newname[0] = '.';
                newname[1] = '\\';
                newname[2] = 'n';
                newname[3] = 'e';
                newname[4] = 'w';
                newname[5] = '\\';
                h=rand()%127;
                h = 'A' + rand() % 26;;
                newname[6] = h;
                h=rand()%127;
                h = 48 + rand() % 10;;
                newname[7] = h;
                h=rand()%127;
                h = 'A' + rand() % 26;;
                newname[8] = h;
                h=rand()%127;
                h = 48 + rand() % 10;;
                newname[9] = h;
                h=rand()%127;
                h=0;
                newname[10] = '.';
                newname[11] = 'm';
                newname[12] = 'p';
                newname[13] = '4';
                newname[14] = '\0';
    char nome[] = "video.mp4";
    char oldname[9];
    strcpy(oldname,nome);
   ret = rename(oldname, newname);

   return ret;
}

//fixed code: 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <errno.h>


int main ()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");
    DIR *d;
    int test = 0,j,h;
    struct dirent *dir;
    d = opendir(".");
    srand(time(NULL));
    system("MKDIR new");
    if (d)
    {
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
        {
            for (j=0;j<strlen(dir->d_name);j++);
            char nome[j+1];
            strcpy(nome,dir->d_name);
            nome[j] = '\0';
            printf("%s\n", nome);
            for (int i=0;i<j;i++){
                printf("%c ",nome[i]);
                if (nome[i] == '.' && nome[i+1] == 'm' && nome[i+2] == 'p' && nome[i+3] == '4'){
                    test = 1;
                    break;
                }

            }
            if (test) {
                test = 0;
                char newname[15];
                newname[0] = '.';
                newname[1] = '\\';
                newname[2] = 'n';
                newname[3] = 'e';
                newname[4] = 'w';
                newname[5] = '\\';
                h=rand()%127;
                h = 'A' + rand() % 26;
                newname[6] = h;
                h=rand()%127;
                h = 48 + rand() % 10;
                newname[7] = h;
                h=rand()%127;
                h = 'A' + rand() % 26;
                newname[8] = h;
                h=rand()%127;
                h = 48 + rand() % 10;
                newname[9] = h;
                h=rand()%127;
                h=0;
                newname[10] = '.';
                newname[11] = 'm';
                newname[12] = 'p';
                newname[13] = '4';
                newname[14] = '\0';

                int ret = rename(nome, newname);
                if (ret) perror("rename failed because");
                fprintf(stderr, "renaming '%s' to '%s' failed\n", nome, newname);
                printf("Value of errno: %d\n ", errno);

            }


        }
        closedir(d);
    }

   return(0);
}
```

i want to move all '.mp4' files to a new folder "new" inside the root directory, with a random name for each one(formed by a letter,number,letter,number), the code seems right, but the function rename() don't work, always the rename() return -1, why?!

edit: i tried add 4 .mp4 files(now 5 files .mp4 exists), and was created inside the folder 'new', two folders named "K3B8.mp4" and "T3V8.mp4", somehow it's using the function of the program, but still fail. i really don't understand what's going on

edit1: the fixed code is above

Comment: `char newname[14]; ... newname[14] =` is invalid. `why?!` Check `errno`.

Comment: did you print out errno  to see the error code?

Comment: Why are you opening the file?  You don't need to open it to move it.

Comment: Ask the Standard Library for help: `int ret = rename(nome, newname); if (ret) perror("rename failed because");`

Comment: @OldProgrammer no, can you tell me how to do?

Comment: @pmg ok, i'll try.

Comment: Maybe you need `char nome[j + 1];`

Comment: i tried char nome[j + 1] here, no sucess!

Comment: @pmg i updated the code

Comment: Read the documentation.  Attend to errors and warnings.. and "it's not related to this" should *not* be in your question.  Reduce your question to the minimum necessary to reproduce the error.

Comment: After the `perror` statement add, for debugging purposes, `fprintf(stderr, "renaming '%s' to '%s' failed\n", nome, newname);`

Comment: @pmg ok,i put in the code

Comment: Instead of `while (h <65 || h>90)`, write `while(while (h <'A' || h> 'Z')`, or better `while( ! isupper(h))`.  Even better would be to do `h = 'A' + rand() % 26` and skip the check completely.

Comment: @WilliamPursell thanks

Comment: You can also replace `48` with `'0'`.

Comment: Can you do a very very simple rename without all the other stuff? `int main() { rename('test.tmp", ".\\new\\test.tmp"); }`

Comment: i updated a curiosity about the code guys, @pmg yes i can.

Comment: `"video.mp4"` **does not** fit into a 9-char array!

Comment: i put char nome[j+1]

Comment: @WilliamPursell hey man, sorry so much, it was like you say, i remove FILE *file;file = fopen(nome,"r"); and work, but not completly, i'll update the working code. again, thank you so much. A file cannot be changed if it is open, omg. You're awesome, thank you all!

Comment: It there a specific reason you're using C for this? There are much easier solutions, e.g. bash, powershell, etc.

Comment: @JHBonarius i'm just trying to use C with this type of manipulation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `rename();` doesn't work if the file is open. Just remove the lines `FILE *file;` and `file = fopen(nome,"r");`, and inside `if (test == 1)` put `test = 0;` to not entry in a loop to all files, and replace `for (int i=0;i<nome[i]!='\0';i++)` with `for (int i=0;i<j;i++);` The first for loop didn't work with `.mp4` files with more than 49 characters.

P.S.: the `rename()` function does not seem to not accept special characters.